# Two label at y-Axis is not represented at a single time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new in d3js and I want to represent two labels at the same node. But, both label are not showing at the node of the graph.There are two labels : one is `d.name` and other is `d.main.temp`, I want to show both.

Here is my code:

```
var sortOrder = false;
var sortBars = function () {
    sortOrder = !sortOrder;

    sortItems = function (a, b) {
        if (sortOrder) {
            return a.main.temp - b.main.temp;
        }
        return b.main.temp - a.main.temp;
    };

    svg.selectAll("rect")
    .sort(sortItems)
    .transition()
    .delay(function (d, i) {
        return i * 50;
    })
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return xScale(i);
    });

    //naming the label(temperature value)
    var m = svg.selectAll('text')
    .sort(sortItems)
    .transition();

    m.delay(function (d, i) {
        return i * 50;
    })
    .duration(1000)
    .text(function (d) {
        console.log(d.main.temp);
        return d.main.pressure;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {console.log(d.main.pressure);
        return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {console.log(d.main.pressure);
        return h - yScale(d.main.temp) + 14;
    });

    m.delay(function (d, i) {
        return i * 50;
    })
    .duration(1000);

    m.text(function (d) {
        //console.log(d.name);
        // console.log(d.main.temp);
        return d.name;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return h - yScale(d.name) + 14;
    })
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("fill", "orange");

// Add the onclick callback to the button
d3.select("#sort").on("click", sortBars);
```

Comment: If instead of `return d.name;`, you use `return d.name + ' ' + d.main.temp`, is that enough for you ?

Comment: Yeah, it works .....Thanks a lot

Comment: posted as an answer for future readers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
return d.name;
```

use

```
return d.name + ' ' + d.main.temp
```

This will join both String in your label